# appending the iframe tag to js in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe, formatter

this is the code snippet from ruby file where the function apply_formatters returns an object which is aligned vertically instead of horizontally. That's why i am trying to implement the iframe tag through javascript.
but the error says:

```
no implicit conversion of Hash into String
```

can someone please comment on whether my approach is correct or not? and what is wrong with this code.

```
js = ''
    js << "\n var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeID');"
    js << "\n iframe = iframe.contentWindow || ( iframe.contentDocument.document || iframe.contentDocument);"
    js << "\n iframe.document.open();"
    js << "\n iframe.document.write(' "
    js << apply_formatters if is_a?(GoogleVisualr::DataTable);
    js << "')"
    js << "\n iframe.document.close();"
    js
```